Error in copyDependecyToDir when using processmapR
I am working on a project where I am going to use process mining, and I have encountered an error I can't seem to find any answer to online, when i use the library processmapR.
The error occurs when I try to draw process map using the function processmapR::process_map(), I get the following error:
Error in copyDependencyToDir(dep, libdir, FALSE) :    Can't copy dependency files that don't exist: '/htmlwidgets/lib/viz/viz.js', '/htmlwidgets/lib/viz/full.render.js'
The error does not occur when i use other plotting functions of processmapR such as trace_explorer or dotted_chart.
I have looked at the directory of processmapR, and I can confirm that both of the files are present.
Why do I encounter this error and what can I do to fix it?
`library(bupaR)`
`library(processmapR)`
`library(readxl)`

`df \<- readxl::read_excel("path to my eventlog in .xlsx format")
`
`df \<- df %\>%
drop_na()`

`eventlog \<- df %\>%
bupaR::eventlog( case_id = 'ID',
activity_id = 'Activity',
activity_instance_id = 'activity_instance_id',
lifecycle_id = 'lifecycle_id',
timestamp = 'TimeStamp',
resource_id = 'resource_id'
)`

`eventlog %\>% process_map()
`

I have tried to re-install processmapR, both using
`remove.packages("processmapR") install.packages("processmapR")`

and
`if (!requireNamespace("devtools", quietly = TRUE)) {   install.packages("devtools") } devtools::install_github("bupaverse/processmapR")`

however, this did not help.

Try installing package processanimateR.
I was facing the same issue and installing this package helped me resolve it.

Yes thank you! It worked!
